# AngularJS: How to set active class to list item when clicked? Ternary method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a newbie to AngularJS with limited Javascript experience. I am trying to set an `.active` class to a ul list item when that item is clicked. I am using ng-repeat directive to list the items. How can I write a ternary expression for my example to work? [**Full plnkr here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SaXDrppIuHngGX26M3va?p=preview).

**View:**

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-click="$index = item.id">
      <a href="#" ng-class="(item.id == $index) ? 'active' : ''">
        <div style="float: left;"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
        <h3 style="padding-left: 5em;">{{item.title}}</h3>
      </a>
</li>
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "Batman",
      "plot": "some stupid plot of a movie."
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Superman",
      "plot": "another plot here."
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Xmen",
      "plot": "asdfadsf asdfasdfasd asdfasdfdsf."
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Avengers",
      "plot": "asdfasdf asdfdddd a3234323 dsfdf."
    }
    ]
});
```

If there is an easier way to do this, feel free to let me know. However, I like the ternary set up.  thanks!

Comment: Why you missed curly braces {{}} around ng-class?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
angular.module('testApp', [])

.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

 $scope.setSelected = function(index) {
  $scope.selected = index;
  console.log($scope.selected);
 }

 $scope.list = [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "Batman",
      "plot": "some stupid plot of a movie."
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Superman",
      "plot": "another plot here."
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Xmen",
      "plot": "asdfadsf asdfasdfasd asdfasdfdsf."
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Avengers",
      "plot": "asdfasdf asdfdddd a3234323 dsfdf."
    }
    ];

}]);
```

```css
.active {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
 <body ng-app="testApp">
  <section ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-click="setSelected($index)">
         <a href="#" ng-class="{'active': item.id == selected}">
           <div style="float: left;"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
           <h3 style="padding-left: 5em;">{{item.title}}</h3>
         </a>
   </li>
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```